# Useless upgrades?

Tags: bloons-td-5, bloons-monkey-city, bloons-td-battles

This is for BTD5, BTD Battles and Bloons Monkey City.

So, there are some upgrades, for example **Technological Terror** on the Super Monkey, that seem the same at 0/4, 1/4 and 2/4 upgrade layouts.

Usually I upgrade first to Plasma Blasts and then to Technological Terror, but is it the same if I upgrade only the 2nd path? Does it have to do anything with popping power or something? Or is it just a waste of money?

This goes also for **Ray Of Doom** on the Dartling Gun, and maybe some other towers I forgot to mention, but these are towers that I actually use, so that will do.

So, **do these upgrades that seem useless at first affect attack speed, popping power or something like that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can assure you that a 2|4 Technological Terror is stronger than a 0|4.  The left sided upgrades will affect its popping power no matter what.

Same goes for the Ray Of Doom.  A 4|0 Ray Of Doom can't and will not pop all bloons. A Ray Of Doom cannot pop lead bloons if it does not have the Depleted Bloontonium Darts upgrade on the right side.

Every upgrade that *seems* useless has some use of some sort.

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong.  Test this in sandbox and you'll see a ROD can pop leads.

Comment: OK, maybe that was a bad example, but seriously, who would not upgrade the right side of a dartling gun before a ray of doom?

Comment: True enough, but those upgrades are useless.